# Help proving formulas in first order logic using axioms of equality

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have been having trouble proving the formulas given in the exercises in the section on equality in First Order Mathematical Logic by Angelo Margaris.

The axioms of equality are given as:

E1. $\forall x (x = x)$

E2. $\forall x_{1} \cdots \forall x_{n} \forall y_{1} \cdots \forall y_{n} ((x_{1} = y_{1} \land \cdots \land x_{n} = y_{n}) \to (G(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) \iff G(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n})))$ (one axiom for each predicate symbol $G$)

E3. $\forall x_{1} \cdots \forall x_{n} \forall y_{1} \cdots \forall y_{n} ((x_{1} = y_{1} \land \cdots \land x_{n} = y_{n}) \to (F(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) = F(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n})))$ (one axiom for each operation symbol $F$)

The first exercise is to prove that if $P(u)$ is similar to $P(v)$, then $\vdash \forall u (P(u) \iff \exists v (v = u \land P(v)))$.

$P(u)$ is similar to $P(v)$ if and only if $v$ is not free in $P(u)$ and $u$ is not free in $P(v)$, and $P(u)$ admits $v$ for $u$ and $P(v)$ admits $u$ for $v$, and $P(v/u)$ is $P(v)$ and $P(u/v)$ is $P(u)$.

Is there a general strategy that may help or any other hints that someone could point me to?

I have been first trying to prove $\vdash P(u) \iff \exists v (v = u \land P(v))$. Is this possible?

EDIT

From Mauro's hint I so far have:

\begin{array}{l l l}
1. & \forall x (x = x) & \text{E1} \\
2. & u = u & \text{T17.1, $\Delta$ is $\varnothing$, $v$ is $x$, $P$ is $x = x$, $t$ is $u$} \\
3. & \quad P(u) & \text{as} \\
4. & \quad u = u \land P(u) & \text{SC, 2, 3} \\
5. & \quad \exists v (v = u \land P(v)) & \text{T17.4, $\Delta$ is $\{P(u)\}$, $v$ is $v$, $P$ is $v = u \land P(v)$, $t$ is $u$} \\
6. & P(u) \to \exists v (v = u \land P(v)) & \text{DT, 1-5} \\
\end{array}

EDIT

If $v = u \to (P(v) \iff P(u))$ holds when $P(u)$ is similar to $P(v)$ (does it?) then perhaps:

\begin{array}{l l l}
1. & v = u \to (P(v) \iff P(u)) & ? \\
2. & \quad \exists v (v = u \land P(v)) & \text{as} \\
3. & \quad \quad v = u \land P(v) & \text{C$v$} \\
4. & \quad \quad v = u & \text{SC, 3} \\
5. & \quad \quad P(v) & \text{SC, 3} \\
6. & \quad \quad P(v) \iff P(u) & \text{MP, 1, 4} \\
7. & \quad \quad P(v) \to P(u) & \text{SC, 6} \\
8. & \quad \quad P(u) & \text{MP, 7, 5} \\
9. & \quad P(u) & \text{C, 3} \\
10. & \exists v (v = u \land P(v)) \to P(u) & \text{DT, 1-9} \\
\end{array}

Steps 3-9 use T17.12 letting $\Delta$ be $\{\exists v (v = u \land P(v))\}$, $v$ be $v$, $P$ be $v = u \land P(v)$, and $Q$ be $P(u)$. $v$ is not free in $\Delta$. $v$ is not free in $Q$ by the definition of similar. Is this correct?

EDIT

I found the following alternative to E2 at Wikipedia:

For any variables $x$ and $y$ and any formula $\varphi(x)$, if $\varphi'$ is obtained by replacing any number of free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$ with $y$, such that these remain free occurrences of $y$, then $x = y \to (\varphi \to \varphi')$.

See E3 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms

If I use this instead of step 1 in my previous edit then perhaps:

\begin{array}{l l l}
1. & v = u \to (P(v) \to P(u)) & \text{alt E2, $P(u)$ and $P(v)$ are similar, hence $P(u)$ is $P(u/v)$} \\
2. & \quad \exists v (v = u \land P(v)) & \text{as} \\
3. & \quad \quad v = u \land P(v) & \text{C$v$} \\
4. & \quad \quad v = u & \text{SC, 3} \\
5. & \quad \quad P(v) & \text{SC, 3} \\
6. & \quad \quad P(v) \to P(u) & \text{MP, 1, 4} \\
7. & \quad \quad P(u) & \text{MP, 6, 5} \\
8. & \quad P(u) & \text{C, 3} \\
9. & \exists v (v = u \land P(v)) \to P(u) & \text{DT, 1-8} \\
\end{array}

Steps 3-8 use T17.12 letting $\Delta$ be $\{\exists v (v = u \land P(v))\}$, $v$ be $v$, $P$ be $v = u \land P(v)$, and $Q$ be $P(u)$. $v$ is not free in $\Delta$. $v$ is not free in $Q$ by the definition of similar. Is this correct?

I think then that the next step is to prove that this version of E2 follows from the version in my book (at the top of my question).

Comment: What have you tried; where did you get stuck? Can you prove the easier $\implies$ direction?

Comment: One thing to ask is "which axioms will I need".  Ax3 deals with functions, so that probably isn't helpful.  Notice that if we interpret $=$ as $\forall x,y ~:~ \lnot(x = y)$, then axiom 2 is true but the theorem is false.  So axiom 1 is necessary for the proof as well as axiom 2.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure I follow. In E2 $G(x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n})$ and $G(y_{1}, \cdots, y_{n})$ are atomic formulas. In step 1, $P(u)$ and $P(v)$ are not necessarily atomic.

Comment: Step 1 is Th.8 page 107.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think I might see how to modify the proof of that theorem to the case where $P(u)$ is similar to $P(v)$, but I'm not sure about using it directly because of the condition that "no variable that occurs in $r$ or $s$ is a bound variable of $P_{r}$". Is it not possible that $u$ may be bound in $P(u)$?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

See Th.17.4 [page 75]: If $\Delta \vdash P(t/v)$, then $\Delta \vdash \exists v P(v)$, provided that...

Assume $\{ P(u) \}$ as $\Delta$ and with equality axiom E1 we have $\vdash u=u$.

Thus:

> $P(u) \vdash u=u \land P(u)$.

Then apply Th.4 to get: $\exists v \ (v=u \land P(v/u))$.

---

For the other "direction", we can start from $\exists v \ (v=u \land P(v))$ and use the *existential elimination* rule [page 40] to get: $t=u \land P(t/v)$.

Then by equality axiom E2 we get: $P(u)$.

Comment: Is it really ok to write $P[v/u]$?  That seems like a weaker claim than establishing the theorem with $P(v)$.

Comment: @DanielV I think $P(v/u)$ is $P(v)$ since $P(u)$ and $P(v)$ are similar.

Comment: @Mauro I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand the process for the other direction. I only seem to be able to get $\exists v (v = u \land P(v)) \to \exists u P(u)$.

Comment: @user695931 Are you familiar with the logic rule $$\dfrac{\exists x ~A,~A \to B,~x \not \in {\rm FV}(B)}{B}$$ ?  Can you figure out what $A$ and $B$ would apply to your problem?

Comment: @DanielV I am not familiar with that rule or notation. What does $FV(B)$ mean?

Comment: @Mauro Which theorem do you mean by existential elimination? Also, I'm not sure how $P(u)$ follows from E2, since $P(u)$ is not a predicate symbol? I am wondering though, do we have $u = v \to (P(u) \iff P(v))$ when $P(u)$ and $P(v)$ are similar? I do not see it as a theorem in this book, but I might see how to modify Theorem 21.8 to prove it.

Comment: @user695931 - rule page 40: from $\exists v P$ infer $P(u/v)$, provided that $u$ is not restricted. This is why I've used a new variable $t$.

Comment: @user695931 - $x \notin FV(B)$ is an abbreviation for: "(the variable) $x$ is **not** free in (formula) $B$". $FB(\varphi)$ denotes the set of variables that have free occurrences in the formula $\varphi$.

Comment: @Mauro I have updated my question to add what I have so far. Is this correct? I believe the proved equivalent of existential elimination is T17.12? I'm sorry, I'm not sure I see how to use T17.12 to get $t = u \land P(t/v)$ or how to use E2 to get $P(u)$ from that. Do you mind showing it in the form I used to show what I have so far?

Comment: @user695931 Have you ever done any proof with or-elimination?

Comment: @DanielV I had to look it up. How would you suggest using it in this proof?

Comment: @user695931 "How do I use Or-Elimination" is worthy of an entire new question on the website.  It is probably the hardest rule to connect with your usual experience.  I suggest asking generally about how to use it (not what it means how whether it is valid etc, but just how to use it) and link back to this question as "this is where my problem came from".

Comment: @user695931 Based on the premises you have and the conclusion you seek, the choice of $A$ and $B$ should be straightforward.  The notation $\dfrac{X}{Y}$ means that if everything above the line ("$X$") is known, then everything below the line ("$Y$") can be concluded.  Can you work out what you know and what you are trying to establish?

Comment: @DanielV I think now I actually just have justify the axiom I found at Wikipedia from the ones in my book? (latest edit to my question)